# React Admin AWS Cognito login not working

Tags: amazon-cognito, react-admin

I am using AWS Cognito as a login for a react admin login. I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-auth-cognito/blob/main/packages/ra-auth-cognito/Readme.md#loginform) and put the info in the App.js file.

This lead to the app.js file containing the following:

```
import { CognitoAuthProvider } from "ra-auth-cognito";
import { CognitoUserPool } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

const dataProvider = unionDataProviderWrapper;

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: process.env[`REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USERPOOL_ID`],
  ClientId: process.env[`REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID`]
});

const authProvider = CognitoAuthProvider(userPool);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Admin
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        dashboard={Dashboard}
        layout={ElectionsLayout}
        authProvider={authProvider}
      >
```

I have confirmed that the user pool and app ID are bringing in the right parameters. I have created a user on the AWS console with a valid email.

When I start the app, I get a simple login. However, logging in with the email and password that I created in cognito does not work.

I am not sure what to attempt to troubleshoot. The user is created in AWS and it is tied in with the user pool id and app id?

Comment: Can you try using the Cognito-hosted UI to cross out any account issues? Update your question please with the output of `aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id xxx --username xxx`, with the response's `UserStatus` field being of particular importance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cognito-hosted UI".

Comment: What results came up when you Googled for 'Cognito hosted UI'?

Comment: I see you are not using the `LoginPage` provided by `ra-auth-cognito`. Can you try using the provided login page? (just like in the example code [here](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-auth-cognito/blob/main/packages/ra-auth-cognito/Readme.md#usage-with-usernamepassword-sign-in))

Comment: I don't really understand how a hosted UI would make a difference in whether or not a login works? This is my big frustration with AWS. I just want to enable cognito sign on. I don't want to use amplify, some hoisted UI, or something else. I just want to enable a cognito pool and its absurdly complicated to figure out.

Comment: So, I tried to use the example at the page listed, but I got this error - 'LoginPage' (imported as 'LoginPage') was not found in 'ra-auth-cognito'. This is another issues that I come across with pretty much every AWS tutorial / install I follow - the examples do not work and there is no explanation.

Comment: So, I had to dig through the code in the ra-auth-cognito repo to figure this out. It turns out that the demo is in fact wrong and the component that needs to be pulled in is "Login" and not "LoginPage".

Seriously, every single AWS demo or install guide I use is wrong. Every, single, one. This one isn't even as wrong as most of them I use.